# PHP date_diff() using variables from a database

Tags: php, sql, datetime, datediff

I have tried to get this date diff function working all night now, its fine until i feed it my two variables.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
<h2>Date diff attempt</h2>
    <?php
    $z = $row->account_add_date;
    $y = $row->start_amount;

    $date1=date_create($z);
    $date2=date_create($y);
    $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
    echo $diff->format('%d days');
    ?>
```

When I run it I get

```
Severity: Warning

Message: date_diff() expects parameter 2 to be DateTime, boolean given
```

Comment: what is this $row->start_amount give?. Is this a date from database?

Comment: Its from a query above to get the variable from the database

Comment: Message means thant your "$z = $row->account_add_date; $y = $row->start_amount;" is not Date time.

Comment: Is this $row->start_amount; a date from database?

Comment: make sure this will return a date and this will help you see it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: @JakirHossain in the database they were date originally, but I have since change the database structure to be date time. I will try to insert new data see if it helps

Comment: `$row->start_amount` is prrobably an int, not datetime

Comment: @Gopal yes they are from the db

Comment: @artm in the database they are both set to datetime not int

Comment: When you print/dump $z and $y, what do you get? It seems you have an error when try to create  `$date2=date_create($y);` . date_create or new DateTime return false if error. You should see what the value of your variable $y.

Comment: @Gopal thank you +1 the link has helped

Comment: what value come this `$y = $row->start_amount;` ?

Comment: One sec, I seem to got something working. but its the wrong difference, but that may be a formatting problem

Comment: @VadivelS you are a life saver ... its 4.19 am, sorry guys i put start_amount not start_time

Comment: Use `%a` instead of `%d` for total numbers of days.

Comment: @Beep: see [DateInterval format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php). You are probably mixing this format with [date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: @Glavić ahh ok +1 for the information, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working properly, I thing there is some problem in your  **$row->account_add_date** and **$row->start_amount**

```
<h2>Date diff attempt</h2>
<?php
$z = "2013-03-15";
$y = "2013-03-31";

$date1=date_create($z);
$date2=date_create($y);
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format('%d days');
?>
```

Comment: Yes there was, i put start_amount not start_date my bad. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$date1 = $row->account_add_date;
$date2 =$row->start_amount;    
$date1 = new DateTime($date1);
$date2 = new DateTime($date2);

echo $date1->diff($date2)->format("%d days, %h hours and %i minuts");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608529/date-diff-expects-parameter-1-to-be-datetimeinterface-string-given